# Get Stages for Particular Opportunity Record Type via REST

Tags: rest-api, opportunity, record-type

So I need to get the Stages for a specific Opportunity Record Type (as defined by the associated Sales Process).  Now I can get it by calling for the describe layout action on that record type and then parsing through the response.

Was wondering if there was a simpler action I could call.

Comment: n.b. with the soap SFDC metadata api, this is straightforward